# Using the mask returned by _mm_cmplt_epi16() to conditionally _mm_set_epi16 using SSE 1 .. SSE4.2

Tags: c++, simd, sse

I'm adding offsets to x- and y-coordinates to then get the color values at the new (x;y), but I have to make sure the coordinates are not out of bounds. So I check if the values are greater than -1 using `_mm_cmplt_epi16(lane, minus_one)`. and I get back a mask.

Now I want to set the values that weren't greater than -1 to 0 so I don't run into access violations and I'm able to get color values.

Once I fetched the color values I want to use the mask again to set the color values to a specific value to not mess up the process, but it seems like there's no `_mm_maskmove_epi16()`

I can only use SSE1-4.2

Is there anything I can do to avoid branches?

Comment: What access violations?  `_mm_set_epi16` takes values, not pointers, so you have to have already dereferenced any pointer(s) before passing as args to it. You can zero some elements with `_mm_and_si128` after you have a vector, but that wouldn't be useful.  Are you trying to do a 16-bit gather with multiple pointers?  Or avoiding crossing into an unmapped page with a contiguous load (like AVX `_mm_maskmove_epi32` could help with, as could AVX-512BW `_mm_maskz_loadu_epi16( _mmask8 k, void const* mem_addr)`.  So is that what you're trying to emulate / work around?)

Comment: @PeterCordes SSE only calculates the (x;y) coordinates, I then look them up in one-dimensional `uint8_t` array, and if there are negatives that results in an access violation. That's why I want to set them to 0. I might get the wrong values but that's ok, I'll ignore them later, and I can't use AVX

Comment: Mask away the negative results before using them as indices, and keep the mask around so you can use it for ignoring the results later.  e.g. `mask = _mm_sria_epi16(v, 15)` / `_mm_andn_si128(mask, v)` to turn the sign bit into a 0 / -1 mask, and then use it inverted with andn.  You should edit your question to include the kind of detail your last comment had, so it actually makes sense and can be answered (or not) by what I suggested in this comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'll play around with it tomorrow, thanks

Comment: If all you want to replace negative `int16` values by `0`, you can simply `_mm_max_epi16(v, _mm_setzero_si128() )`.

Comment: @chtz: Oh yes of course, that's better that my `srai` / `andn` idea.  I was only thinking of `blendv` instructions, and was missing the 1-instruction way.